# Adding host (VM) to Red Hat Satellite 6.4 throws error

Tags: rhel, redhat-satellite

When I try to run bootstrap command I get below error:

```
RUNNING], [2019-05-13 13:58:15], [Calling Foreman API to create domain mytestdomain.com associated with the org & location]
An error occured: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity
url: https://redhat-satellite-64.mytestdomain.com:443/api/v2/domains
code: 422
data: {
"domain": {
"location_ids": [
2
],
"name": "mytestdomain.com",
"organization_ids": [
1
]
}
}
error: {
"error": {
"errors": {
"name": [
"has already been taken"
]
},
"id": null,
"full_messages": [
"Name has already been taken"
]
}
}
```

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: by the way i tried other names as well

Comment: I've edited your question to make it slightly more readable with code formatting. However, you should [edit] so that the code excerpt has the same format/indentation as the actual error message. I also changed the tag from the one related to satellite communication systems. You should also include details about how your system has been configured and the command you ran to generate the error. As it stands, the question may be too broad to be answerable. See [ask]

Comment: Can you confirm whether "mytestdomain.com" (or possibly "finastra.com") already exists, based on "Name has already been taken"?

Comment: no  sorry that doesnt exist.I am testing on mytestdomain.com. I have updated my original question with correct domain